# Trying to use Python to parse a docx document in xml format to print words that are in bold

Tags: python, xml

I have a word docx file that I would like to print the words that are in **Bold** looking through the document in xml format it seems the words I'm looking to print have the following attribute.

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00510F21">
  <w:rPr><w:b/>
     <w:noProof/>
     <w:sz w:val="22"/>
     <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>Print this Sentence</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Specifically the `w:rsidRPr="00510F21"` attribute which specifies that the text is bold.  Below is more of the XML document give a better idea of the structure.

```
<w:p w14:paraId="64E19BC3" w14:textId="4D8C930F" w:rsidR="00FF6AD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF6AD1" w:rsidP="00C11B48">
<w:pPr>
   <w:ind w:left="360" w:hanging="360"/>
   <w:jc w:val="both"/>
   <w:rPr>
       <w:sz w:val="22"/>
       <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
   </w:rPr>
 </w:pPr>
 <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:b/>
       <w:noProof/><w:sz w:val="22"/>
       <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Some text</w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r w:rsidRPr="0009466D">
     <w:rPr><w:i/><w:noProof/>
          <w:sz w:val="22"/><w:szCs w:val="22"/>
     </w:rPr>
     <w:t>For example</w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r>
     <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
     </w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">
     </w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r w:rsidRPr="00510F21">
     <w:rPr>
         <w:b/>
         <w:noProof/>
         <w:sz w:val="22"/>
         <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
     </w:rPr>
     <w:t>Print this stuff</w:t>
 </w:r>
```

After doing some research and trying to do this with the Python-docx library I've decided to try using `lxml`.  I was getting an error about the namespace and tried to add that namespace but it's returning an empty set.  Below is some of the namespace stuff from the document.

```
<w:document
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"  xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"            xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
```

Below is the code I'm using.  Again I'd like to print if the attribute is `w:rsidRPr="00510F21"`.

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse("document.xml")

namespaces = {'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}

wr_roots = root.findall('w:r', namespaces)
print wr_roots # prints empty set

for atype in wr_roots:
   if w:rsidRPr == '00510F21':
       print(atype.get('w:t'))
```

Comment: Why not use python-docx?

Comment: For one thing, docx doesn't yet handle change-tracked insertions and deletions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to find all the bold text you can use `findall()` with an [`xpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) expression:

```
from lxml import etree

namespaces = {'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}

root = etree.parse('document.xml').getroot()
for e in root.findall('.//w:r/w:rPr/w:b/../../w:t', namespaces):
    print(e.text)
```

Instead of looking for `w:r` nodes with `w:rsidRPr="00510F21"` as an attribute (which I am not convinced denotes bolded text), look for run nodes (`w:r`) with `w:b` in the run properties tag (`w:rPr`), and then access the text tag (`w:t`) within. The `w:b` tag is the bold property as [documented here](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtextFormatting.php).

The xpath expression can be simplified to `'.//w:b/../../w:t'` although this is less rigorous and might result in false matches.

Answer (score 1):

Consider lxml's `xpath()` method. Recall `.get()` retrieves attributes and `.find()` retrieves nodes. And because the XML has namespaces in attributes, you will need to prefix the URI in the `.get()` call. Finally, use the `.nsmap` object to retrieve all namespaces at the root of the document.

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse("document.xml")
root = doc.getroot()

for wr_roots in doc.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=root.nsmap):
    if wr_roots.get('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}rsidRPr')\
       == '00510F21':
        print(wr_roots.find('w:t', namespaces=root.nsmap).text)

# Print this stuff
```