# extracting data from xml of .docx document

Tags: python, regex, xml, pandas

I need to extract the data between  tags as mentioned below.Also,I want to concatenate the data if the data is in  corresponding to the same id.

For examle,as per the below XML both  tags are within the  tabs corresponding to the same id "00F1234A"
Hence "Hello World" needs to be extracted.

```
xml_string="
<w:r w:rsid="00F1234A">     
    <w:rPr> 

    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Hello</w:t>
</w:r>   


<w:r w:rsid="00F1234A">     
    <w:rPr> 

    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">World</w:t>
</w:r>"
```

currently, am extracting data between  tags with the following regex

```
re.findall("<w:t>(.+?)</w:t>",xml_string)
```

this gives me Hello, but not Hello World

how can i concatenate the data in  corresponding to the same id,which in this case is "00F1234A"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to parse this, you'll need the namespaces from the XML (`xmlns: x = "urn:something"`).

Use etrees to extract the values instead of regex like so:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#parse XML string
tree = ET.fromstring('xml_string')

#declare namespace dictionary
nsmap = {'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}

tagvalues = []
#loop through all w:t tags and append their values to list
for i in root.findall('.//w:r//w:t', nsmap):
    tagvalues.append(i.text)

#concatenate all values into a string
string  = ''
[string.join(word) for word in tagvalues]
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188140/trying-to-use-python-to-parse-a-docx-document-in-xml-format-to-print-words-that) as well.

Comment: thanks..but what does this line do?
```
nsmap = {'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}
```

Comment: nsmap (namespace map) is the same as the namespaces variable. edited my answer so it's used. Passing a namespace map to root.findall allows you to forego typing the uri `schemas.openxmlformats...` in place of the `w` in your xpath query `'.//w:t` every time there's a `w`. URI's ensure that XML namespaces are uniform across documents and that there can't be duplicate namespaces. Docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) and Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

Comment: Did this answer your question?